Where is the documentation that describes and explains the output of the ip link command?
Here is some fake/sample output of the ip link command.
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
3: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000

From what website or book can I learn what this output means?

Unfortunately the terminology used in the output of ip has only little to do with the usage of ip or Ubuntu itself (it's for the most part networking-related jargon)

The documentation is already on your computer.  Read man ip-link. Or, you could see which package provides it with dpkg -S $(type -p ip), use apt source to download the source, and read, read, read.
